# Why does calling csrf_token() in my Flask app throw a "can't concat tuple to bytes" error?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, csrf-token

I'm trying to include the X-CSRFToken header in a `fetch()` call, and according to Flask-WTF [documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.14.2/csrf.html?highlight=csrf_token#javascript-requests), making a call to csrf_token() from your template will return the token in your code.  However, my app throws an error when I make the `csrf_token()` call.

The error states: "can't concat tuple to bytes."  Traceback is included below.  This is the Javascript within the template that is rendered via `render_template()`

```
    <script>
        const form = document.querySelector("form");

        form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            let opts = {
                method: this.method.value,
                headers: new Headers({
                    "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                })
            };

            if(this.method.value!="GET"){
                opts.body = this.data.value;
            }

            fetch( this.api_endpoint.value, opts );
        });
    </script>
```

And below here is the .py file that routes calls `render_template()`

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

bp = Blueprint('main', __name__,
    template_folder="templates",
    static_folder="static")

@bp.route("/")
def index():
   return render_template("home.html")

@bp.route("/apitester")
def apitester():
    return render_template("apitester.htm")
```

And here is the **init**.py file where in the `app` and `csrf` objects are instantiated

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect, CSRFError
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

csrf = CSRFProtect()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)

    app.config.from_object('application.appsettings')

    db.init_app(app)

    csrf.init_app(app)

    @app.errorhandler(404)
    def page_not_found(e):
        return render_template('404err.htm', reason=e.description), 404

    @app.errorhandler(CSRFError)
    def handle_csrf_error(e):
        return render_template('400err.htm', reason=e.description), 400

    with app.app_context():
        from exercises.bp import bp as bp_exercise
        from main.bp import bp as bp_main
        from application.models import Exercise

        app.register_blueprint(bp_main, url_prefix="/")
        app.register_blueprint(bp_exercise, url_prefix="/exercises")

        return app
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\csrf.py", line 49, in generate_csrf
    token = s.dumps(session[field_name])
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\serializer.py", line 167, in dumps
    rv = self.make_signer(salt).sign(payload)
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\timed.py", line 42, in sign
    return value + sep + self.get_signature(value)
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\signer.py", line 143, in get_signature
    key = self.derive_key()
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\signer.py", line 130, in derive_key
    return self.digest_method(salt + b"signer" + self.secret_key).digest()
TypeError: can't concat tuple to bytes

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\pyeip\main\bp.py", line 14, in apitester
    return render_template("apitester.htm")
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 137, in render_template
    return _render(
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\pyeip\main\templates\apitester.htm", line 36, in top-level template code
    const token = {{ csrf_token() }};
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\csrf.py", line 52, in generate_csrf
    token = s.dumps(session[field_name])
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\serializer.py", line 167, in dumps
    rv = self.make_signer(salt).sign(payload)
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\timed.py", line 42, in sign
    return value + sep + self.get_signature(value)
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\signer.py", line 143, in get_signature
    key = self.derive_key()
  File "C:\pyeip\venv\Lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\signer.py", line 130, in derive_key
    return self.digest_method(salt + b"signer" + self.secret_key).digest()
TypeError: can't concat tuple to bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the last part of your traceback

> ```
> return self.digest_method(salt + b"signer" + >self.secret_key<).digest()
> ```

Check the SECRET_KEY value in your Flask app's config (or `app.secret_key`), look for extra comma after the secret string.

Eg:

```py
SECRET_KEY = "very secret string", # extraneous comma, it's tuple
```

Comment: Nailed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is expecting a string here.  Try:

```
const token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
```

To prove this, view the page's source code in your browser to see the `const token=` declaration currently.

Comment: Thank you for catching that; but, the error remains.  I think what you pointed out is only considered client-side syntax error rather than a server error.

Comment: If you are sending a csrf token as an undefined object, it will crash the verification function on the server.  Any dashes in the token become minus signs, etc.  Can you show the source now for your `csrf_token`?

Comment: I've updated my post to show the code, but not sure what you meant exactly by "source ... for your csrf_token"  It's part of Flask-WTF CSRF Protection, so it's not source code I wrote

Comment: I mean, in your browser, Developer > View Source.  That will show exactly what is rendering on the page.